# Defining a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How would I go about defining a string in python?  I'm having issues

```
def printName(x):
    msg = "Welcome to class, "
    print(msg, self.name)

printName(john)
```

In this situation, I am trying to figure out what I am supposed to put after the function "printName" and make it so the string that it calls (in this case john) will show up, and print the message "welcome to class, john"

Please note that I am a beginner.

I want to set it up so I type into the shell

```
>>> printName(john)
```

and it'll return "Welcome to class, john"

Obviously, I could do this with a very simple `print()` command, but I need to know how to do it with the defined printName command.  I am using Wing101 on 3.3.5

Comment: I think you're getting ahead of yourself here. Regular functions do not use `self`. That is typically exclusive to class methods. The function you have now will not work no matter what you replace `john` with.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily do it as follows

```
def print_name(name):
    print("Welcome to class, {0}".format(name))

print_name("John")
```

As far as your own solution is concerned, I don't know what you are doing.

1. what is `self`
2. It should be `john` instead of john

**For Edited question**

```
def printName(x):
    msg = "Welcome to class, "
    print(msg + x) # '+' is concatenation symbol in python, no self variable exists here

printName('john') # Since it's a string should be quoted
```

Comment: what is the {0} for?  And I just edited - how would I go about making it so if I were to type in print_name(john) in the shell it would return the desired message?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for something like this:

```
def printName(name):
    msg = "Welcome to class, "
    print(msg, name)

person = 'John'
printName(person)
```

Note that I'm assigning a variable `person` to the string 'John', then passing that variable to the function. The function receives the parameter into the local variable `name` and prints that variable along with the message.